# Is there a Google API for the Google Vault product?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-apps

I'm looking for a way to extract emails from the Google Vault email archive database.  I see there is a way to put data in, through their email migration API, but not out.  I am aware of the Vault licensing API but that is not what I need.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access Vault via API. You would need to manually export the user data via the Vault UI.

Answer (score 1):

Google now has documentation about the API [here](https://developers.google.com/vault/).